# how to find out synonym or related sentence of a word in a given text file using nltk

Tags: compare, nltk, synonym

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
fp = open("inpsyn.txt")
data = fp.read()

#to tokenize input text into sentences

print '\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data))# splits text into sentences

#to tokenize the tokenized sentences into words

tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(data)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
words = [w.lower() for w in text]  
print words     #to print the tokens

for a in words:
    print a

syns = wn.synsets(a)
print "synsets:", syns

for s in syns:
    for l in s.lemmas:
        print l.name
    print s.definition
    print s.examples
```

i do not find any code related to my question. If there is any please mail me the link.
this is a code which will not find synonyms from a given text file or related sentence

Comment: what is your aim? what's your input/output? can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as a coding error - look where you define `a` in the loop (`for a in words`). Now look further where you try `syns=wn.synsets(a)`. In this case `a` is not defined outside the loop. What you want is include all your synsets code within the `for a in words` loop. Here is what you want altogether:

```
...

words = [w.lower() for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(data)]   # other lines in your code are just excessive

for a in words:
    syns = wn.synsets(a)
    print "synsets:", syns

    for s in syns:
         for l in s.lemmas:
             print l.name
         print s.definition
         print s.examples
```

That's a bit of a silly mistake. Also, please learn some cleaner coding - the current is very untidy and painful to look at.

Comment: other than the errors in the code, i think the OP also wants to do some other things but i've no clue about it...

Comment: I agree, alvas. The code looks so rough that we might have to wait some time for a clear response as to what the OP wants to achieve.. Didn't want to post as answer - more as a comment - but couldn't include so much code in comment format..